# Showing autocompletetextview results as suggestions above keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, autocompletetextview, landscape-portrait

I have an autocompletetextview and it works very well but I would like to show the results as suggestions above the keyboard. 
It does this by default when in landscape mode, but not when in portrait.
Is there a way I can force it to do the same in portrait?

[Picture of portrait mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CVmV.png)

[Picture of landscape mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSLyR.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `android:dropDownHeight="XXdp"` for your `AutoCompleteTextView` tag in your Layout file.

**Edit** : You can also try adding code below to your activity definition of your Manifest File:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

or

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Comment: @Arash did you find any solution for that problem if you remember you can help me now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try add in the `AutoCompleteTextView` xml file.

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```